# Does Overcooked adapt depending on the number of players?

Tags: overcooked

I'm playing with my SO, and some kitchens seem pretty hard. Like it's balanced to have 4 people cutting and frying and making soup, and we are at a disadvantage since we play in 2 player coop.

So does the game adapt when you play alone, with 1 friend or with a full party of 4, or do you have an advantage playing the game with 4 players?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, the game adjusts the points needed for stars depending on how many players there are. For instance, I was playing with 3 friends a few weeks ago and we struggled to get three stars. However, two friends left at one point and I was able to get three stars when it was only me and another friend due to the required points being very much reduced (I believe we only needed to complete 5-6 dishes to get 3 stars?).

Comment: Ok so the points needed adapt, but the layouts of the kitchen don't I guess?

Comment: @Fredy31 not that I've seen, no.

Comment: Pretty sure it's just stars and points that change based on the players, I think the kitchens are always the same. The common theme seems to be "2 players = well oiled machine, 4 people = chaos but fun"

Comment: @n_palum Evidently too many cooks spoil the broth.